Virtual interface pair forwarding packets to each other
The goal is very simple: anything sent to pair1, as outgoing packet, should appear on pair0 as an incoming packet and vice versa. I am thinking on a layer3-only, virtual interface now.
tun could do this, but it would require a userspace program for the packet forwarding. I do not want it.
Does it exist?

I see there is veth, that is already very close, but still L2. I want an L3 thing. If there is none, L2 might be an acceptable compromise but my idealistic solution is L3.

The question was already asked 9 years ago and still no answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194697/is-there-a-thing-like-veth-but-without-link-level-headers

I have found ipvlan, that is more like a switch but at least L3. I think a dummy device with bridge modus ipvlan aliases would work as we want to. I am now experimenting with it.

@A.B Afaik 9 years ago, there was no ipvlan yet. At the time, multiple ip address on the same l2 was the top and we regularly closed ourself out by ifconfig down-ing ip aliased network interfaces :-) I think, today, there exists already solution for the task. And that would be an answer.

Okay, dummy + macvlan combo works. Linux rulez!

macvlan is layer 2. Even ipvlan is displayed as layer 2 (it has an Ethernet MAC address and says link/ether) but at least in l3 mode doesn't use ARP. I hope at least you meant ipvlan.

@A.B Yes, exactly ipvlan! Sorry it was very late already. Yes it looks an l2 device, and tcpdump is even giving l2 headers on it! :-) The fun thing is that they have the same source and dest, random hwaddr. I am curious, what would happen if I would give a link-level addr 00:00:00:00:00:00 to a dummy device. Although I think it might be because the dummy0 what I am duplicating, is also l2. Anyways, problem reduced to the need for an l3 dummy or lo device.

@A.B okay. With tunctl, one can create an l3-only interface, originally for vpns but in our case, only to multiply it with ipvlan to a local-only network between netns-es.
